# join and group table a rows by table b dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

I have two `m:m` tables, `profile_wordcards` and `profile_activities`. I want to group all wordcards by activity creation dates, where `profile_id = 2`.

I.e., if an `activity 1` was created on `2019-01-19 2:12:05`, any wordcard created on or before that date should be grouped by `activity 1`. If an `activity 2` was created on `2019-01-19 2:14:22`, all wordcards created on or before that date should be grouped by `activity 2`, and so on.

Table: **profile_activities**

```
activity_id | profile_id | created_at
------------------------------------------
1              2            2019-01-19 2:12:05
2              2            2019-01-19 2:14:22
```

Table: **profile_wordcards**

```
wordcard_id | profile_id | created_at   
-----------------------------------------   
386         2             2019-01-19 2:04:07    >> Everything below: less than activity 1 created at    
385         2             2019-01-19 2:05:19        
263         2             2019-01-19 2:05:19        
234         2             2019-01-19 2:11:49        
175         2             2019-01-19 2:12:02        
201         2             2019-01-19 2:12:02        
226         2             2019-01-19 2:12:04        
409         2             2019-01-19 2:12:05        
361         2             2019-01-19 2:12:05        
359         2             2019-01-19 2:12:25    >> Everything below: less than activity 2 created at    
188         2             2019-01-19 2:12:34        
227         2             2019-01-19 2:12:59        
187         2             2019-01-19 2:13:01        
228         2             2019-01-19 2:13:18        
384         2             2019-01-19 2:13:37        
177         2             2019-01-19 2:14:00        
225         2             2019-01-19 2:14:00
```

Desired Output:

```
wordcard_id | profile_id |  created_at     | activity_id | activity_created_at
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- GROUP 1 (ACTIVITY ID 1, any wordcard.created_at <= 2019-01-19 2:12:05)
-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
386             2       2019-01-19 2:04:07     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
385             2       2019-01-19 2:05:19     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
263             2       2019-01-19 2:05:19     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
234             2       2019-01-19 2:11:49     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
175             2       2019-01-19 2:12:02     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
201             2       2019-01-19 2:12:02     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
226             2       2019-01-19 2:12:04     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
409             2       2019-01-19 2:12:05     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
361             2       2019-01-19 2:12:05     1           2019-01-19 2:12:05
-- GROUP 2 (ACTIVITY ID 2, any wordcard.created_at <= 2019-01-19 2:14:22 but > 2019-01-19 2:12:05) 
-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
359             2       2019-01-19 2:12:25     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
188             2       2019-01-19 2:12:34     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
227             2       2019-01-19 2:12:59     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
187             2       2019-01-19 2:13:01     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
228             2       2019-01-19 2:13:18     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
384             2       2019-01-19 2:13:37     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
177             2       2019-01-19 2:14:00     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
225             2       2019-01-19 2:14:00     2           2019-01-19 2:14:22
```

I've tried:

```
select pwc.wordcard_id, pwc.created_at, pa.activity_id, pa.created_at, pwc.profile_id
from profile_wordcards pwc
left join profile_activities pa on (pa.created_at < pwc.created_at)
where pwc.profile_id = 2
order by activity_id asc
```

But this is returning a) activity IDs not attached to profile 2 and b) not grouping as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining `profile_activities` directly join a subquery that selects all columns from `profile_activities` and also the `lag()`ed `created_at`. Then you can compare against the `created_at` of the "previous" activity. For the default value for `lag()`, that gets taken when no previous activity exists, use `'-infinity'`. As all timestamps are larger than negative infinity, the comparison against the wordcard `created_at` will work in that cases too.

```
SELECT w.wordcard_id,
       w.profile_id,
       w.created_at,
       a.activity_id,
       a.profile_id,
       a.created_at
       FROM (SELECT a.activity_id,
                    a.profile_id,
                    a.created_at,
                    lag(a.created_at,
                        1,
                        '-infinity') OVER (ORDER BY a.created_at) created_at_lag
                    FROM profile_activities a) a
            INNER JOIN profile_wordcards w
                       ON w.profile_id = a.profile_id
                          AND w.created_at > a.created_at_lag
                          AND w.created_at <= a.created_at
       ORDER BY a.activity_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=0c91d6933fff4ca9d65501060a08d7fd)

Comment: Amazing work! `LAG` is great and the use of `infinity` to capture items below the first activity `created_at` threshold is great